# Phonegap/Cordova returns same image when using window.requestFileSystem()

Tags: cordova

I have a strange issue..

I need to get several (4) images from the iOS simulator phone gallery, and I update the src of each of 4 images to show them. When not using window.requestFileSystem() I can get them OK, but as they are stored in tmp it is no good because they are lost when the app reloads, and I want them to persist (I save the path in localstorage so I can upload them later if the user was offline when they got them).

So I started using the filesystem to save the files, but when using window.requestFileSystem(), getting each image returns the same first image I chose, no matter what image I chose. It looks like navigator.camera.getPicture returns the same photo everytime when using filesystem.

I wonder if anyone knows what I am doing wrong. Here is my entire JS.

```
// -----------------------------
// INIT
// -----------------------------
var networkState;
var pictureSource;
var destinationType;
var storage = window.localStorage;

console.log(storage);

// Listeners for online or offline status
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
// Wait for device API libraries to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


// When Device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady()
{
    //localStorage.clear();

    console.log("onDeviceReady");

    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, FileIO.gotFS, FileIO.errorHandler);

    networkState = checkConnection();
    if(networkState == 'online')
    {
        sendLocalStorage();
    } 
}

// -----------------------------
// File System
// -----------------------------

// set some globals
var gImageURI = '';
var gFileSystem = {};

var FileIO = {

    // sets the filesystem to the global var gFileSystem
    gotFS : function(fileSystem) {
        gFileSystem = fileSystem;
    },

    // pickup the URI from the Camera edit and assign it to the global var gImageURI
    // create a filesystem object called a 'file entry' based on the image URI
    // pass that file entry over to gotImageURI()
    updateCameraImages : function(imageURI) {
        console.log(imageURI);
          gImageURI = imageURI;
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, FileIO.gotImageURI, FileIO.errorHandler);
       },

    // pickup the file entry, rename it, and move the file to the app's root directory.
    // on success run the movedImageSuccess() method
    gotImageURI : function(fileEntry) {

        var newName = fileEntry.name;
        fileEntry.moveTo(gFileSystem.root, newName, FileIO.movedImageSuccess, FileIO.errorHandler);
    },

    // send the full URI of the moved image to the updateImageSrc() method which does some DOM manipulation
    movedImageSuccess : function(fileEntry) {
        updateImageSrc(fileEntry.nativeURL);
        console.log("Image1URL: "+fileEntry.nativeURL);
    },

    // get a new file entry for the moved image when the user hits the delete button
    // pass the file entry to removeFile()
    removeDeletedImage : function(imageURI){
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, FileIO.removeFile, FileIO.errorHandler);
    },

    // delete the file
    removeFile : function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.remove();
    },

    // simple error handler
    errorHandler : function(e) {
         var msg = '';
         switch (e.code) {
         case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
                break;
          case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                break;
          case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
                break;
          case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
                break;
          case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
                break;
          default:
                msg = e.code;
          break;
        };
      console.log('Error: ' + msg);
    }
}



// -----------------------------
// Photo Functions
// -----------------------------


// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI, image)
{
    FileIO.updateCameraImages(imageURI);
}

function updateImageSrc(newImage)
{
    var image = "image2";
    console.log(newImage);

    // Get image handle
    var galleryImage = document.getElementById(image);

    // Unhide image elements
    galleryImage.style.display = 'block';

    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    galleryImage.src = newImage;

}


// A button will call this function
function capturePhoto(image)
{
    console.log("capturePhoto: "+image);

    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(imageData)
        {
            onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData, image);
        },
        onFail,
        {
            quality: 70,
            targetWidth: 1000,
            //targetHeight: 600,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        }
    );
}



// -----------------------------
// Button Functions
// -----------------------------

// A button will call this function
function getPhoto(source, image)
{
    console.log("getPhoto: "+image);

    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function(imageData)
    {
        onPhotoURISuccess(imageData, image);
    },
    onFail,
    {
        quality: 70,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        //targetHeight: 600,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source
    });
}



// -----------------------------
// Save Functions
// -----------------------------

// Save to Local Storage
function save()
{
    // Create a the ID number for this form submission

    // Create Date for formid
    var dt = new Date();
    var datetime = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + dt.getHours() + '-' + dt.getMinutes() + '-' + dt.getSeconds();

    // Create and Set formid
    var formid = datetime + '-' + convertToSlug($('#name').val());
    $('#formid').val(formid);

    // Get images
    var imageURI1 = document.getElementById('image1').getAttribute("src");
    var imageURI2 = document.getElementById('image2').getAttribute("src");
    var imageURI3 = document.getElementById('image3').getAttribute("src");
    var imageURI4 = document.getElementById('image4').getAttribute("src");

console.log("Image1URL: "+imageURI1);

    var images = {imageURI1:imageURI1, imageURI2:imageURI2, imageURI3:imageURI3, imageURI4:imageURI4};
    var imagesJSON = JSON.stringify(images);

    storage.setItem(formid, imagesJSON);


    // If online, send
    if(networkState == 'online')
    {
        sendLocalStorage();
    }

}






// Upload files to server
function sendLocalStorage()
{

    if(localStorage.length > 0)
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
       {
           var formid = localStorage.key(i);
           var imagesJSON = storage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
           var images = JSON.parse(imagesJSON);

            // Get images
           var imageURI1 = images.imageURI1;
           var imageURI2 = images.imageURI2;
           var imageURI3 = images.imageURI3;
           var imageURI4 = images.imageURI4;


           if(imageURI1!="")
           {
            $('#image1_process').show();
               fileTransfer(imageURI1, formid, "1");
            }

           if(imageURI2!="")
           {
                $('#image2_process').show();
               fileTransfer(imageURI2, formid, "2");
            }

           if(imageURI3!="")
           {
                $('#image3_process').show();
               fileTransfer(imageURI3, formid, "3");
            }

           if(imageURI4!="")
           {
                $('#image4_process').show();
               fileTransfer(imageURI4, formid, "4");
            }

        }
    }


}

function fileTransfer(imageURI, formid, imageNum)
{

    console.log("send: "+imageURI);

    name = formid + "-" + imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=name;
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.fullpath = imageURI;
    params.name = name;
    params.formid = formid;

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload( imageURI, "http://myserver/upload.php",
       function(result)
       {
            //upload successful   
            console.log('send result:');
            console.log(result);
            console.log('Hide #image'+imageNum+'_process');
            $('#image'+imageNum+'_process').hide(); 

            if ( $(".image_process:visible").length === 0)
            {
                console.log('Sending email');
                sendEmail(formid);

                // Delete localstorage if exists
                localStorage.removeItem(formid);

            }

       },
       function(error)
       {
          console.log('Error:');
          console.log(error);
            message('Upload unsuccessful, error occured while upload');
       },
       options
    );
}


function sendEmail(formid)
{
    console.log("sendEmail: "+formid);

    var postData = $( "#regform" ).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        url: 'http://myserver/email.php',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data);
            console.log('Email sent');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(data);
            message('There was an error submitting the form');
        }
    });



}



// -----------------------------
// Network Functions
// -----------------------------


// IF ONLINE THEN SEND IMAGES



// Handle the online event
//
function onOnline()
{
    console.log("onOnline");
    networkState = 'online';
    sendLocalStorage();
}

function onOffline()
{
    console.log("onOffline");
    networkState = 'offline';
}

function checkConnection()
{
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    console.log("Network State: "+networkState);

    if(networkState == 'none' || networkState == 'Connection.NONE')
    {
        return 'offline';   
    }
    else
    {
        return 'online';    
    }
}






// -----------------------------
// General Functions
// -----------------------------

function message(message)
{
    $('#messages').html(message);   
}

function convertToSlug(Text)
{
    return Text
       .toLowerCase()
       .replace(/ /g,'-')
       .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'')
       ;
}

// Called if something bad happens.
function onFail(message)
{
    alert('onFail: ' + message);
}
```

My HTML is as follows, I have put the getPhoto() onClick event on the div that contains the `<img>` so this then gets filled with the image.

```
<div class="image-box" id="image1_div" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY, 'image1'); return false;">
            <img style="display:none;width:50px;height:50px;" id="image1" src="" />
            <span class="image_process" id="image1_process" style="display: none">Uploading</span>
        </div>

        <div class="image-box" id="image2_div" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY, 'image2'); return false;">
            <img style="display:none;width:50px;height:50px;" id="image2" src="" />
            <span class="image_process" id="image2_process" style="display: none">Uploading</span>
        </div>

        <div class="image-box" id="image3_div" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY, 'image3'); return false;">
            <img style="display:none;width:50px;height:50px;" id="image3" src="" />
            <span class="image_process" id="image3_process" style="display: none">Uploading</span>
        </div>

        <div class="image-box" id="image4_div" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY, 'image4'); return false;">
            <img style="display:none;width:50px;height:50px;" id="image4" src="" />
            <span class="image_process" id="image4_process" style="display: none">Uploading</span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it to work. I had to assign a new image name for the fileEntry.moveTo function. I wonder if choosing the image in iOS simulator (maybe others) assigns it the same name every time, and so a new unique image name is specifically needed to be set to allow storage of multiple images. The following works for me now.

```
gotImageURI : function(fileEntry, image) {

        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        //new file name
        var newName = n + ".jpg";

        fileEntry.moveTo(gFileSystem.root, newName, function(fileEntry)
        {
            FileIO.movedImageSuccess(fileEntry, image); 
        }, FileIO.errorHandler);

    },
```

Note: I am passing the successCallback movedImageSuccess as a function so I can pass it an additional variable "image" in my case, which is used to update the correct image later. If you are not passing extra variables you are more likely to use the following:

```
gotImageURI : function(fileEntry) {

        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        //new file name
        var newName = n + ".jpg";

        fileEntry.moveTo(gFileSystem.root, newName, FileIO.movedImageSuccess, FileIO.errorHandler);

    },
```